# Good Servers to use with app

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ftp

So currently I am using Webs.com to upload .plist files and html files and such so that my apps can fetch them from there for free. However, Webs.com server is unreliable and often down or slow. So I was hoping I could get some advice on what I can use for the following uses, Is there anything free? If not, I am willing to pay (just not too much!)

-Upload and fetch .plist files from app
-Upload and fetch .html files from app

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you add some more details to make it easier to answer this.  In particular how are you uploading and downloading the files? I assume through http?  How big are the files, and how many are there?  Are you uploading files for your app to download? or are your apps uploading files?

Comment: @Will The sizes of the files are relatively small, There are many of them though So I'm thinking anything around 2-4GB of server space. The apps for the most part are downloading the files(ex the plist is fetched and put into an array) At the same time It would also be nice to be able to upload files from the app. Right now I have been uploading them through http

Comment: @Will Also I would like to be able to use push notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic way to to this was to run your own server on the cloud.  You aren't responsible for the hardware but you still need to keep it running and updated.  Various people offer this, e.g. Rackspace mentioned above.  Having your own server can be the most flexible solution but can also require more effort and maintenance on your part.

Cloud file hosting like amazon s3 might be a better option for you.  This is a software-as-a-service offering so all the details are abstracted away from you.  You can just upload and download files as you see fit.  This can work out a lot cheaper, you only pay for what you need.  You could be looking at less than a dollar a month.

File uploads are easy in principle but you will need to think about how you design your whole system.  How will you control who uploads what?  How will you be able to find the right content?

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace Cloud would be a solution. You can get a linux server for about $20/month.

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/